# Rails Loop in the Loop

Tags: loops, ruby-on-rails-4, each

I have Post model, and loop for display Post in the index page. I have Comment which belongs to Post, so In the show Post page I have used loop `<% @comments.each do |comment| %>` `<%= comment.body %>` `<% end %>`. But the post has a Response, so when I write "loop response in the loop comment" after clicking `Add Response` I have an alert

> The response has successfully added

but it doesn't show under the Comment, i think that it's broken loop:

My code in the `post#show`

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>

  <p> Author: <%= comment.user.nickname %></p>
  <p><%= comment.body %></p>

  <%= link_to "Add a response to comment!",
        new_post_comment_response_path(@post, comment) %>

  <% @responses.each do |response| %>
    <%= response.body_response %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Is it wrong?

Comment: Please provide the content of config/routes.rb

Comment: What is `@responses`?

Comment: Assuming the variables are assigned as expected the code looks correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do `@responses.each do |response|` because you haven't defined a `@responses` instance variable in your controller... and you can't do so because each `responses` collection is different for each `comment`

Assuming you have a `has_many :responses` in your Comment class you can do...

```
  <% comment.responses.each do |response| %>
```

Comment: So I just do that, and: Under the Comment I have all responses, not only ones that belong to comment id. My @responses in def show end method is: 
    `@responses = Response.where(:comment_id => params[:comment_id]).order("created_at DESC")`

I want to get responses which belong to id under the comment. How to get it? Thanks for all responses! I'm glad!

Comment: "comment belongs_to Post and has many:responses"  So you (should) have a method "comment.responses" and you should use that. If you do `@responses = Response.where(post_id: @post.id)...` you're going to get all the responses for the post. As you say you're seeing.  Did you try the code in my answer?

Comment: When I use @responses= Response.find(params[:review_id]) i have an error: "Couldn't find Response with 'id'="

Comment: WHY are you doing that? That's not what my answer suggested.  My answer says change your view file to use `<% comment.responses.each do |response| %>`  You don't need a `@responses` instance variable.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you, so if i don't set @responses in Post controller, but only change the view file, the responses are not showing still. 

my view: 
<% comment.responses.each do |response| %>
<%= comment.response.body %>
<% end %>

It's not working

Comment: I add to database (in response migration) :comment_id, and is "nil" maybe it's the problem?

Comment: Yeah, you would need the responses to have a `comment_id` when you create them.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you want is that you will have a post, which can have many comments and there will be responses to the comments.

This is what should be there in your models:

```
Post.rb --> :has_many comments
Comment.rb --> :belongs_to post

Comment.rb --> :has_many responses
Response.rb --> :belongs_to comment
```

Post this, you can do the following:

## To show all comments of a particular post and the responses to them

```
@post = Post.find(:id) 
@comments = @post.comments

@comments.each do |comment|
    puts comment.info
    puts comment.author
    @responses =  comment.responses
    @responses.each.do |response|
         // Considering the response resource has attributes info, likes, unlikes
         puts response.info
         puts response.likes
         puts response.unlikes
    end
end
```